# Statements equivalent to “ X is a connected metric space”

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I would appreciate some comments about a proof I am trying to do.

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, we need to prove that these three propositions are equivalent :

1. X is connected ( X is connected iff X cannot be written as a disjoint union of two non empty open subsets of X)
2. X cannot be written as the union of two non-empty separated sets.
3. The only two clopen subsets of $X$ are $X$ and $ \emptyset $.

The proof will consist in showing that 1 iff 3 and 2 iff 3. Of course, if thats true, 1 iff 2 is true.

1 iff 3 : X is connected metric space. Suppose that A is a clopen subset of X. Let $B = X/A$ (The complement of A in X). We have that, since complement of clopen is clopen, B is clopen. Also $ X = A \cup B $ (X a disjoint union of A and B).
By definition of connected, A and B cannot be both empty. Therefore, one of the two is empty, and therefore the other is X. This means that A is X or $ \emptyset $

Now, the other part : We have that the only two clopen subsets of X are X and $ \emptyset $.
Suppose that X is not connected. Then we can write X as a disjoint union of A and B, both non-empty open subsets of X. That means that A is closed because A is complement of B in X. A is clopen, and this contradicts the hypothesis. Therefore X is connected.

So 1 iff 3 is true.

2 iff 3 : We have that X is not the union of two non-empty separated sets.
Suppose that 3 is false. Let A be a non-empty proper clopen subset of X. If we make  B = X\A  , we have B non- empty ( because A is proper subset) and clopen (because B is complement of A in X). We have that A and B are separated and also $ X = A\cup B $. This is a contradiction with hypothesis

Now, the only clopen subsets of X are X and $ \emptyset $.
Suppose that 2 is false, that is, X can be written as the union of two non- empty separated sets A and B. Since A and B are separated, A and B are disjoint.
We have that X can be written as the union of two disjoint sets $ X = A \cup B   $. So X is not connected, and this means that there exist a proper clopen subset of X ( contrapositive of If 3 then 1). This is contradiction

So 2 iff 3 is true.
Since  1 iff 3 and 2 iff 3 are true, 1 iff 2 is true too.

Thats my work. Comments?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't even use the definition of "separated"....

Comment: less work is to show $1 \implies 2 \implies 3 \implies 1$ and is more common to do as well.

Comment: When you say “ you dont use the def of separated” do you mean that the proof is wrong or that its unnecesary all the work i am doing?

Comment: It's a clear hint your proof must be incomplete as you do not use a single fact nor the definition of separated subsets.